# Axios send wrong cookies (CORS)

Tags: http, nginx, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I am using local development server (on my computer) for frontend. Backend is located on another server and I sending requests from frontend to backend using CORS.

It works ok, but when I passing cookies from frontend, It passed incorrect: namely the csrf token is different from what is stored in cookies.

Examples:

Cookies on Chrome dev tools, Application tab: `csrf_token: b2o3q06llj`

[image]

Request headers:

[image]

As you can see, header Cookie is **different from data viewed on Application tab**. X-Csrf-Token is correct, but `Cookie` header is wrong. It must contain `csrf_token` which is available on `Dev tools > Application >  Storage > Cookies`

CORS setup in Nginx config (remote server):

```
if ($request_method ~* "(GET|POST)") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://192.168.1.127:3000' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range, X-Csrf-Token, Cache-Control' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
      }

      # Preflighted requests
      if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  'http://192.168.1.127:3000' always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" 'true' always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD" always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Csrf-Token, Cache-Control" always;
        return 204;
      }
```

Axios setup:

```
axios.create({
    baseURL: window.location.protocol + '//' +window.location.hostname +  (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '') + '/data',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-Csrf-Token': <token>,
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    },
    withCredentials: true
});
```

I can not understand what the problem is. Why does axios not send correct cookies?

Comment: I don't see what wrong here.
Is the header X-Csrf-Token wrong?

Comment: X-Csrf-Token is correct, but `Cookie` header is wrong. It must contain `csrf_token` which is available on Dev tools > Application >  Storage > Cookies

Comment: Also, `document.cookie` contains `csrf_token`

Comment: could you update with image of cookies in Application tab.

Comment: @manhmaluc, updated

Comment: I have no idea about this. So sorry.

Comment: I'm having same problem with Django app with django-subdomains and one subdomain for my api that looks like 'api.project.local'
I had a problem with session cookie not being passed with axios and withCredentials: True. The solution was to set in Django settings.py SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.project.local'   <- notice the dot '.' preceeding the domain. I did the same for CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN that allowed axios to pass the correct csrftoken cookie.